# How to add current date/time to clink/cmder prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, clink, cmder

I'm a rather happy user of [clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/) via the great [cmder](https://cmder.net/) package. The only thing I miss is an easy way to set the command prompt to display the current date/time (and last exit code, history number, as in `bash`... etc).

Could someone point me to the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: Can you just use the Windows `date /t`? Also, Windows stores the last exit code in `%errorlevel%`, while sh uses `$?`. Try those.

Comment: But how to integrate that output to the prompt? I don't want to run `date /t` every time before running some long-running command.

Comment: Oh. Go see `prompt /?`, there's a date and time option in there. Again, that's standard Windows command prompt - I have no idea what clink or cmder do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this prompt settings (example only, it's show how you can call any console application inside "prompt printing"). Note! It works in ConEmu only.

```
prompt $p$s$e]9;7;"cmd /c echo (%DATE% %TIME%)"$e\$g
```

But, as Bob said, there is an easier way:

```
prompt $p$s$d$s$t$s$g
```

And for `cmder` you should edit the supplied `init.bat` as that defines the prompt settings.

Comment: For cmder, the suggested way to edit prompt settings is in `%CMDER_ROOT%\config\user-startup.cmd` and not `init.bat`.

Comment: On win7 with Cmder, adding `$t` did the trick for me : `@prompt $E[1;32;40m$P$S{git}{hg} $t$S$_$E[1;30;40m{lamb}$S$E[0m
`

Comment: @wegry this `%CMDER_ROOT%\config\user-startup.cmd` file didn't seem to have any effect on my configuration. Maybe was I doing it wrong.

Comment: @Benj It didn't seem to work for me at first either, but a restart later it did? I'm mystified by what made start working.

Comment: @wegry Well, let's say both methods are OK...

Comment: in 2018 for me worked `prompt cmd /c echo ($t$s) :$p$g` to add to the `user-profile.cmd` file (windows10).

Comment: Where are the prompt settings for conemu?

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsEnvironment.html

Answer (score 12):

The answer provided by [Maximus](https://superuser.com/a/702599/137964) is no longer valid for *cmder* 1.3+

You have to create a `.lua` file (for ex. `my_prompt.lua`) inside your *cmder* `config` folder with your customized definition [(source)](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/338#issuecomment-236418658).

Below my customization:

```
function custom_prompt()
  cwd = clink.get_cwd()
  prompt = "\x1b[1;32;40m{cwd} {git}{hg} \n\x1b[1;30;40m{time}\n{lamb} \x1b[0m"
  new_value = string.gsub(prompt, "{cwd}", cwd)
  add_time = string.gsub(new_value, "{time}", os.date("%x - %X"))
  clink.prompt.value = string.gsub(add_time, "{lamb}", "λ")
end

clink.prompt.register_filter(custom_prompt, 1)
```

And this is the resulting prompt

```
C:\
03/25/17 - 20:56:14
λ
```

You can find more customization options for the time output in the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html)

---

update for comment reported error

```
function time_prompt()
    os.setlocale ("", "time")
    local cwd = clink.get_cwd()
    local prompt = "\x1b[1;32m{cwd} {git}{hg} \n\x1b[30m{time}\n{lamb} \x1b[0m"
    local new_value = string.gsub(prompt, "{cwd}", cwd)
    local add_time = string.gsub(new_value, "{time}", os.date("%x - %X"))
    clink.prompt.value = string.gsub(add_time, "{lamb}", "λ")
end
```

Comment: Maximus answer is correct, but this is the best answer!

Comment: `D:\Tools\cmder\config\my_prompt.lua:1: unexpected symbol near char(255)`  and the prompt looks like: `1:26.51)"←\\`

Comment: mmm I don't know what is that, but checking again my lua file it's not exactly as the old code I posted, tell me if using the one I'm updating now is working.

Comment: Comment from @Edwin in Maximus' answer worked for me.  `prompt cmd /c echo ($t$s) :$p$g` in `user-profile.cmd`

Comment: This alone doesn't change anything on my git bash prompt in cmder. Is cmder supposed to read and execute all .lua files in the config folder at startup?

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets the above script is to modify the `cmd.exe` shell with `clink` via lua programming, it has nothing to do with the `bash` shell. Check the `bash` documentation for prompt customizing.

Comment: @Gruber it didn't do anything to my cmd prompt either, but that's probably because I already have the powerline prompt which comes with its own .lua files. What worked for me is what I wrote below in my answer. Maybe it will help someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

One line modification for cmder. Put it to cmder\config\my_config.lua

```
function my_prompt_filter()
    cwd = clink.get_cwd()
    prompt = "\x1b[1;32;40m{cwd}{git}{hg} $> \x1b[33;40m"
    new_value = string.gsub(prompt, "{cwd}", cwd)
    clink.prompt.value = string.gsub(new_value, "{lamb}", "λ")
end

clink.prompt.register_filter(my_prompt_filter, 1)
```

result:

```
C:\Users\user1 $>
C:\Users\user1 $> date
The current date is: 02.02.2018
C:\Users\user1 $>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here worked for me, so I ended up with adding the following line in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias myprompt='export PS1="\[\e]9;9;"\w"\007\e]9;12\007\]\[\033]0;$MSYSTEM:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\] \D{%T}\nλ "'
```

That last part `\D{%T}` is what shows the current time (don't care about the date, as usually I need to know how much time has ellapsed since I started a task).

Of course, this doesn't automatically change the prompt on all git bash terminals. You have to execute the `myprompt` command on the default prompt to change it.
I tried to just do the above export inside the `.bashrc` file but I was getting an error. Maybe someone will have a better idea on how to get around that.